# Цикл непрерывного генерирования сигнала ЦАП

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Мне надо сделать цикл, в котором непрерывно будет генерироваться сигнал и излучаться с ЦАП. Пишу я это на C#. При непрерывном генерировании сигнала должна быть возможность изменения его параметров, поэтому, собственно, и нужен циклический режим генерирования.

Как один раз сгенерировать сигнал я знаю(сигнал генерируется  ЦАП, но параметры его менять нельзя). 
При создании цикла, в котором происходит задание сигнала и запуск генерации, с ЦАП излучается скачущий сигнал нужной формы.  Часть сигнала просто отображается скачущей прямой (может не успевает сформироваться), хотя при однократном генерировании прямой нету и быть ее не должно, и сигнал не скачет. Также при циклическом генерировании сигнала Windows Form становится недоступной (зависает по видимому). На Windows Form ничего нельзя изменить, и она не двигается. 
Как сделать, чтобы сигнал генерировался не скачущим и полностью(без прямых линий вместо сигнала)? и при этом чтобы Windows Form была активна в процессе циклического генерирования сигнала.

Comment: while (true) { } - непрерывный цикл =)
while (true) { foo(a1, a2); }
много тексте, я вообще не очень в вопрос вьехал, там больше какой то схематехнической терминологии, чем программирование

Comment: Я такой непрерывный цикл и создаю, при каждом прохождении происходит формирование сигнала и запуск генерации сигнала. При этом Windows Form зависает, ее нельзя ни подвинуть, ни вести значение в label, ни кнопку нажать и т.д.

Comment: Наверное стоит его запускать в отдельном потоке, чтобы форма не зависала.

Comment: Не наверное, а точно так и надо =)

Comment: BackgroundWorker идеально подойдёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В фоновом потоке следует запускать процесс, обновляющий данные. А поток пользовательского интерфейса перерисовывается по модели данных. Чтобы перерисовка была не слишком тяжёлой, прокидывать в поток пользовательского интерфейса сообщения нужно с незаметной задержкой. Пока обрабатывается одно сообщение, сообщения, возникающие параллельно, игнорируются, следующее дошедшее до интерфейса сообщение актуализирует его полностью.